# Azure container app job finishes but stalls until eventual timeout

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps, azure-container-app-jobs

I have a container app job which runs for about 1 hour. The process starts on schedule at 2am, finishes ~3am, but stalls until it reaches its 2 hour timeout and is marked as a failed execution (system logs in pic below).

This behaviour started on March 14th and happens on every nightly execution. Before this date it was working perfectly.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

[image: Container app job system log]

Vaguely similar to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/1071) github issue but their executions are not marked as failed.

EDIT: Tried some things.

- Simplified the container to just an `echo` . Same result.
- Removed all unneeded stuff from the container config (env variables, connections to file share). Same result
- Created a separate container app env outside of my vnet. Runs finish SUCCESSFULLY.

Not a solution but seemingly closer. This failing behaviour started on the same day that DNS changes to our organisation were changed. Can't understand why a DNS change would cause a container app job to fail but could possibly be related.

Comment: The behavior you are experiencing with your Azure container app job is likely related to the DNS changes made to your organization on March 14th, it is possible that the change is affecting the network connectivity required for your job to complete successfully. You may want to investigate further by reviewing your network configuration

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of original cause but destroying and redeploying container app environment and container app jobs has caused them to start being marked as succeeded again.

I would assume the issue to have been cause by the DNS changes.